# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[DemoComponent])NullInjectorError: No provider for MapsAPILoader

Tags: google-maps-api-3, angular17, agm-core

I have implemented google maps in my project of `angular 17` , I am using `@agm/core` and `@types/googlemaps` I had implemented my `AgmCoreModule` in my `main.ts` file as my project is standalone I do not have app module in my project , so I have written the code in root module i.e `main.ts` in providers array. But it is not able to find `AgmCoreModule` and so the error comes. Please guide me what is alternative of `@NgModule` in angular 17 , where do we need to put that code, I have tried writting it in `importProvidersFrom()` in `app.config` but it does not work. Also when I pass `AgmCoreModule` inside imports array in `demo.component.ts` but it shows error. Any help will be appreciated.

`main.ts`

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { appConfig } from 'app/app.config';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "fuse-angular",
    "version": "19.0.0",
    "description": "Fuse - Angular Admin Template and Starter Project",
    "author": "https://themeforest.net/user/srcn",
    "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/standard",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
        "@angular/animations": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "17.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "17.0.1",
        "@angular/material-luxon-adapter": "17.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "17.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "17.0.3",
        "@ngneat/transloco": "^6.0.4",
        "@types/google.maps": "^3.55.1",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
        "apexcharts": "3.44.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
        "highlight.js": "11.9.0",
        "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
        "luxon": "3.4.4",
        "ng-apexcharts": "1.8.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^17.0.1",
        "ngx-mask": "^17.0.4",
        "ngx-quill": "24.0.2",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.5",
        "quill": "1.3.7",
        "rxjs": "7.8.1",
        "tslib": "2.6.2",
        "zone.js": "0.14.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.0.1",
        "@angular/cli": "17.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "17.0.3",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "0.5.10",
        "@types/chroma-js": "2.4.3",
        "@types/crypto-js": "3.1.47",
        "@types/highlight.js": "10.1.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "5.1.2",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.201",
        "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.11",
        "@types/luxon": "3.3.4",
        "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
        "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
        "jasmine-core": "5.1.1",
        "karma": "6.4.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
        "karma-coverage": "2.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.21",
        "postcss": "8.4.31",
        "tailwindcss": "3.3.5",
        "typescript": "5.2.2"
    }
}
```

`app.config`

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
 providers: [
  importProvidersFrom(
            AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
                apiKey: environment.googleApiKey,
                libraries: ['places', 'geometry'],
              }),
          ),
]
}
```

`demo.component.ts`

```
import { PathService } from 'app/modules/shared/services/path.service';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

 
 @ViewChild('search1')
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
  geoCoder: google.maps.Geocoder;
  constructor(
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private path: PathService
  ) {

  }
ngOnInit(){
  this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
          const addressData = this.path.getGoogleAddress(place.address_components);
          // this.clickRegionValue = false;
          console.log("addressData",addressData);
          
          // this.form.controls.sourceAddress.patchValue(
          //   {
          //     'pinCode': addressData.pincode,
          //   });

          // this.sourceRegion = addressData.region;
          // this.sourcePinCode = addressData.pincode;

          // this.souceLat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          // this.souceLng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        });
      });
    });
}
```

`demo.component.html`

```
div class="sm:col-span-2">
            <mat-form-field class="w-full">
              <mat-label>pincode</mat-label>
              <input
                placeholder="Enter pincode"
                type="number" #search1 
                id="pac-input"
                matInput
                formControlName="pincode"
              
              />
            
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```